# An error should pop when the site account number in the site sheet is different from the account number in the account sheet

Tags: java, angular, typescript

In the below code whenever the account number in the site sheet is different from the account number in the account sheet than an error has to be shown in the front end

** "No matching Account in Account tab found - unmapped"**

```
private ResiContractImportResultBuilder convertToRelational(
            List<AccountInformation> accounts,
            List<SiteInformation> sites, 
            List<ContainerInformation> containers, 
            List<RateInformation> rates, 
            List<RouteInformation> routes) {
        
        Map<String, List<? extends Row>> sheetsPreview = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        sheetsPreview.put(ACCOUNT_SHEET_NAME, accounts);
        sheetsPreview.put(SITE_SHEET_NAME, sites);
        sheetsPreview.put(CONTAINER_SHEET_NAME, containers);
        sheetsPreview.put(RATE_SHEET_NAME, rates);
        sheetsPreview.put(ROUTE_SHEET_NAME, routes);
        
        //routes
        Map<String, List<RouteInformation>> routesMap = routes.stream()
                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(RouteInformation::getParentKey));
        
        //rates
        Map<String, List<RateInformation>> ratesMap = rates.stream()
                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(RateInformation::getParentKey));
        
        containers.forEach(c -> {
            c.setRates(ratesMap.remove(c.getKey()));
            c.setRoutes(routesMap.remove(c.getKey()));
            if(c.getRoutes() != null) {
                c.getRoutes().forEach(r -> {
                    r.setContainer(c);
                });
            }
        });
        
        //container
        Map<String, List<ContainerInformation>> containersMap = containers.stream()
                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ContainerInformation::getParentKey));
        
        sites.forEach(s -> {
            s.setContainers(containersMap.remove(s.getKey()));
        });
        
        //sites
        Map<String, List<SiteInformation>> sitesMap = sites.stream()
                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SiteInformation::getParentKey));
        
        accounts.forEach(a -> {
            a.setSites(sitesMap.remove(a.getKey()));
        });
        
        
        logger.debug("sites not mapped {}", sitesMap.values().size());
        logger.debug("containers not mapped {}", containersMap.values().size());
        logger.debug("rates not mapped {}", ratesMap.values().size());
        logger.debug("routes not mapped {}", routesMap.values().size());

        Multimap<String, RowError> unmappedSheetRows = LinkedListMultimap.create(); 
        sitesMap.values().forEach(l -> {
            l.forEach(ll -> {
                unmappedSheetRows.put(SITE_SHEET_NAME, 
                        new RowError(ll.getRowIndex() - 1, "No matching Account in Account tab found - unmapped"));
            });
        });
        
        containersMap.values().forEach(l -> {
            l.forEach(ll -> {
                unmappedSheetRows.put(CONTAINER_SHEET_NAME, 
                        new RowError(ll.getRowIndex() - 1, "No matching Site in Site tab found - unmapped"));
            });
        });
        
        ratesMap.values().forEach(l -> {
            l.forEach(ll -> {
                unmappedSheetRows.put(RATE_SHEET_NAME, 
                        new RowError(ll.getRowIndex() - 1, "No matching Container in Container tab found - unmapped"));
            });
        });
        
        routesMap.values().forEach(l -> {
            l.forEach(ll -> {
                unmappedSheetRows.put(ROUTE_SHEET_NAME, 
                        new RowError(ll.getRowIndex() - 1, "No matching Container in Container tab found - unmapped"));
            });
        });
        
        ResiContractImportResultBuilder builder = ResiContractImportResult.builder()
                .unmappedRows(unmappedSheetRows.asMap());
        
        builder.accounts(accounts);
        builder.sheetsPreview(sheetsPreview);
        
        return builder;
    }
```

Lately when I run the program it throws the NUll point exception in this line

**Map<String, List> siteGroups = sitios.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SiteInformation::getAccountNumber));**

this is the associated code

```
    private static void siteNumberValidator(AccountInformation row, List<String> errors) {
        List <SiteInformation> sitios = row.getSites(); 
        Map<String, List<SiteInformation>> siteGroups = sitios.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SiteInformation::getAccountNumber));
        siteGroups.entrySet().stream().map(entrySet -> entrySet.getValue()).forEach(siteGroup -> {
            int size = siteGroup.size();
            if (size == 1){
                if (!siteGroup.get(0).getSiteNumber().equals("1")){
                    errors.add("Associated Site must have an id of 1");
                }
            } else {
                int max = siteGroup.stream().map(SiteInformation::getSiteNumber).map(Integer::valueOf).max(Integer::compare).get();
                for (int i = 1; i < max; i++){
                    Integer index = Integer.valueOf(i);
                    boolean validateSiteNumber = siteGroup.stream().map(SiteInformation::getSiteNumber).map(Integer::valueOf).anyMatch(siteNumber -> siteNumber.equals(index));
                    if (!validateSiteNumber) {
                        errors.add("Associated Sites must be sequential starting at 1");
                    break;
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

could you please help me with it if needed I can share the SiteInformation file too.

Comment: you tagged the question with `javascript` ... there seems to be no `javascript` present

Comment: sorry my bad I have updated

Comment: I have resolved it by including the entire siteGroup in a if statement checking for null